# How does quartz track the time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

How does quartz track the time ? Is it a continuous timer running in background or does it somehow uses the OS scheduler or is it something else ?

Which class actually holds this feature ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I digged into Quartz source code, I found (at least for `StdScheduler` implementation which is proxy of `QuartzScheduler`) that its scheduling thread `QuartzSchedulingThread` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` for prediction of the next job trigger run.

Please look inside [QuartzSchedulerThread.java](http://svn.terracotta.org/fisheye/browse/Quartz/trunk/quartz/src/main/java/org/quartz/core/QuartzSchedulerThread.java?r=HEAD) .