# Quartz - change how the current time is determined?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to change how a Quartz scheduler decides what the current time is?

I am developing a service-based application, including a time service that is responsible for providing the current time on demand (so that we can control the current time for testing purposes).

Our scheduling service uses Quartz under the hood. It would be nice for scheduling to respect the 'correct' current time when under test, rather than the time as determined by  `System.currentTimeMillis()` or similar.

(I think that the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951121/how-does-quartz-track-the-time) might suggest that I can't do this, but I hope that I'm wrong...)

I'm using Quartz version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question in NO, you cannot do that.

Earlier on Quartz tried to account for such a need, but there got to be so many components with so many different lifecycles (instantiators, etc.) that need to determine current time that the plumbing necessary for it became very unwieldy and it was given up.

Comment: This for me is a critical feature. Without it any testing is not possible. I don't imagine waiting hours and days to see the results of a single test pass.

The above explanation seems rather like a poor excuse for lazyness. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to define your own Scheduler that wraps (or inherits) the StdScheduler. In your overrided `scheduleJob(...)` method, you wrap the supplied `Trigger` with a wrapper-implementation where you, for instance, override the `getStartTime()` and/or `getNextFireTime()` methods to return the wrapped triggers return value plus or minus some interval that represents the offset of your "test" time against the "real" time.